# Boolean value always returns true

Tags: java, json, boolean

In this method:

```java
ReadJson IDI = new ReadJson();
boolean IsDisadvantage = IDI.getDis();
if(IsDisadvantage = true) {
    System.out.println("Disadvantage Activated\n");
    setDisadvs();
} else if(IsDisadvandage = false) {
    System.out.println("Disadvantage Deactivated\n");
}
```

It always returns *true* even if it's set as false.

Comment: In java you compare with `==`, not with `=`. `IsDisadvantage = true` will be always be true no matter what is the value of `IsDisadvantage`. Change it to `if (IsDisadvantage == true)` or just `if (IsDisadvantage)`

Comment: @Amongalen Ok wasn't aware,very simple thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java comparing is done with `==` instead of `=`.

Fixed code:

```
if(IsDisadvantage == true)
          {
              System.out.println("Disadvantage Activated\n");
              setDisadvs();
          }
          else if(IsDisadvandage == false)
          {
              System.out.println("Disadvantage Deactivated\n");
          }
```